# Keep all variables of a df when applying group_by and summarise with date?

Tags: r, date, group-by, dplyr

I only need the first survey of a repeating census with the same individuals,
so I choose the first time the person gave the interview, which works, but I get a new object without all other variables of the inital df. How can I keep all columns?

```
df$var1 <- df%>%strptime(var1, "%Y-%m-%d")
survey_1 <- df%>% group_by(per)%>% summarise(var1 = min(var1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `summarize` to `filter`

```
df %>% group_by(per) %>% filter(var1 == min(var1))
```